# Where can you find the native code in the JDK?

Tags: java

I was looking at the Java code for FileInputStream and am interested in what the open and close methods do.  These functions, or parts of them, are implemented natively.  Do you know where I can find this code? Is this code part of the open source license for the JDK?

Comment: Fostah: Could you please post the link once you find it on the links TofuBeer sent?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/source_license.html
http://download.java.net/jdk6/source/
http://openjdk.java.net/
http://www.gnu.org/software/classpath/
```

Here is a link to the FileInputStream code... there is also code specific to Windows and presumably other platforms inthe approriate directories.

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/0a5b87833562/src/share/native/java/io/FileInputStream.c

Comment: The link form your answer is broken. Couldn't you provide the working one?

Comment: @St.Antario I think that is the updated link. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks much. BTW, don't you know the URL for clonning the jdk-source code repo __entirely__? In particularly, I need to get all native method implementations.

Answer (score 4):

[OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/) should have everything you search for, e.g. the [Java 7 mercurial (hg) repository](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7). A [zip file](http://www.java.net/download/openjdk/jdk7/promoted/b48/openjdk-7-ea-src-b48-19_feb_2009.zip) with everything from Feb 21th is also available.

If you don't want the brand new developer stuff from Java 7, there is also everything for the well known Java 6.

Answer (score 3):

The Sun source is available from [java.net](https://jdk6.dev.java.net/).

For FileInputStream, `j2se/src/share/native/java/io/FileInputStream.c`. If you replace `native` with `windows`, `solaris` or `linux` there will be platform specific code in those directories. JDK7 has a slightly different structure.