# I want to know the actual implementation behind a method, Eg: To create a file in Java, use createNewFile()

Tags: java, api, function

I am achieving the result by using the Java API.
To explain what i need, i want to ask you with an example.

E.g:
To create a File in Java, there is a function in the File class, it is "createNewFile()".
So, we can create a new File, by mentioning:

```
File file1=new File("c:\\file1.txt");
if(!file1.exists())
file1.createNewFile(); 


    .... and complete the code with try catch.
```

Result is: A new File will be created in the mentioned Drive [ C: ]. 
NOW, i want to know how this is actually done. How, file1.exists(), .exists() actually checks the file is already there are not, like this.. i want to know the implemetnation, to know better understanding of API and the logic behind.

I tried looking into the JDK \ src folder, and in Eclipse IDE,i can even see the source flow, by clicking on the File class, then ... .

BUT,

I am not getting the logical implementation, rather i can see the interfaces, abstract classes, and the use of final private volatile keywords, and a few lines of code that is pretty high level.

In a single line, my question is:
How to do the function task, by not using the function name just like that. Know further.

Comment: I'm willing to bet that some (if not all) of these functions have some native code.

Comment: please guide me, where to look at, and the way to understand the implemtation. I can do a Ctrl+ and click the class name and its function name. But, to understand completely, what way to follow.

Answer (score 2):

You can always check [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/).  For example, the [Open JDK 7 `File.createNewFile()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/io/File.java#File.createNewFile%28%29) source code is shown:

```
public boolean createNewFile() throws IOException {
  SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
  if (security != null) security.checkWrite(path);
   return fs.createFileExclusively(path);

 }
```

where `fs` declared as

```
static private FileSystem fs = FileSystem.getFileSystem();
```

and `getFileSystem()` is documented as

```
//Return the FileSystem object representing this platform's local filesystem.
public static native FileSystem getFileSystem();
```

Here, the clue is in the `native` keyword.  It specifies that the implementation of this method lies with the operating system of the machine that is being used.  You can also implement your own variants of this functionality by using the [Java Native Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html).

Note that OpenJDK is the open source version of Java and is intended to be a drop-in replacement of Oracle's closed source implementations.  While the actual code may differ slightly, the actual functionality is pretty much equal to Oracle's offerings.

Comment: Hi, i can see the similar explanation in Java documentation. But, instead of all the high level information, like you mentioned above, where can i find the logic behind, a new file, or for example any methd implementations. E.g: i dont want to use strlen(), to find string length, i want to learn how it work

Answer (score 1):

Operations such as file IO are OS-dependent, so their implementation is in native code, which will be in a lower level language with calls specific for the OS on which it's designed to run.

I refer you to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587317/where-can-you-find-the-native-code-in-the-jdk) for where to find the source of the native code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read Java source codes to research implementation of its inside.
Oracle Java is not opensource, so you can't read sources.

You can look source code of OpenJDK, but I am sure that it differs from Oracle Java.

Comment: In fact in recent versions (7+) oracle java **is** open source: it is almost entirely based off openjdk sources + some minor proprietary components.

Comment: I will try to understand the source of OpenJDK. As i will be seeing this for the first time, i hope i wil go in the correct direction. Thanks for the reply Nicolai. I am now thinking of one of my mentor, earlier who actually showed how to implement the strlen(), etc method implementations, without using those methods. I hope i can see and learn like that way. Please let me know how to best use OpenJDK

Answer (score 0):

The reasons they only have the interfaces is because a lot of these are implemented in whatever language that the runtime itself is implemented in, e.g. C++ for OpenJDK or Oracle JDK. The File API is mostly just a wrapper around the system calls of the operating system you're working on, e.g. POSIX if on Linux/Unix or WinAPI on Windows.

You can download the source code of OpenJDK and see how these native functions are implemented.

> How to do the function task, by not using the function name just like that.

You'll need to write a native method that makes a system call. Like in Java, in C/C++ also have these system calls wrapped in a nice file API.

But if you want to implement a system call yourself without using any of the nice API, a system call itself is basically just a software interrupt with special values in the CPU registers to determine which system call is being called. As you can probably guess now, you'll need a language that supports raising software interrupt to make system calls directly, such as assembly or alternatively C/C++ with inline assembly.

A software interrupt is basically just a special kind of jump/goto that can only jump to the interrupt handler in the kernel code; unlike regular jump, software interrupt is special in that it also switch the CPU from the user mode to kernel mode (e.g.  [Ring 0](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28computer_security%29) in x86-based systems). Code running in the kernel mode has a higher privilege than code running in user mode; running in kernel mode enables privileged instructions that can do direct hardware access (among other things), this allows the OS kernel to service the system call. The OS typically will have device drivers that understand the specifics of each hardware.

Once the kernel finishes servicing the system call, the kernel will raise another interrupt to switch back to user mode and return to where the program was left off before.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try to download the OpenJDK, and the subject you are talking is somehow needs my effort to understand completely. Anyhow, i will try to implement. Thanks.

Comment: @sai_ana: You'll likely need to use a language that allows inline assembly like C or C++ if you want to learn to reimplement a system call like file API without any of the nice wrapper functions. I haven't checked OpenJDK source code, but it probably just uses the nice wrapper functions in C++ standard library or OS API rather than reimplementing it from scratch. But if that is what you want, it's worth it to check out the source code for glibc. A system call is an entirely different beast than a pure function like strlen().